# A difficult, concise, and applicable complex analysis book.

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I am currently going through Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*. I love the concision (only around 150 pages), and the problems are at just the right level for me (although I'd still be very happy if they were harder). I am wondering if you know of any books that are similar (and meet some extra criteria) that cover the basics of Complex Analysis. Ideally, the problems would require brain-work, be short, and have applications (not limited to the sciences: applications within mathematics would be cool too and possibly appreciated even more).

What I may be asking for might not exist, or even worse, self-contradictory. For example, if the book is filled to the brim with applications of the book's theorems to other branches of mathematics, how can it be concise? That said, I would really appreciate it if you recommended a book that you enjoyed that met all or most of these criteria.

Have a great day,
Brian

Comment: You might check out "Complex Analysis" by Ahlfors.

Comment: +1 on Ahlfors. For nice exercises, there is also "Problems and Theorems in Analysis" by Pólya & Szegő.

Comment: I would hardly call Ahlfor's *applicable*.

Comment: But it does require brain work :-) And learning from the first to receive the Fields medal is a pleasure.

Comment: There is also "Applied and Computational Complex Analysis", by Henrici, that may be more suitable for applications (though it stays within mathematics).

Comment: Thank you all! I am still deciding although I just asked my parents for "Problems and Theorems in Analysis" for my birthday. This site is awesome!